# warn delaying request, excess: by zone

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress-плагины

Появились такие ошибки связанные с кроном:

```
2018/12/02 00:40:01 [warn] 7736#7736: *208931 delaying request, excess:         0.940, by zone "***.eu", client: 185.***.***.***, server: ***.eu, request: "GET /request-cres.html?id=22 HTTP/1.1", host: "***.eu"

2018/12/02 00:40:01 [warn] 7738#7738: *208932 delaying request, excess: 1.940, by zone "***.eu", client: 185.***.***.***, server: ***.eu, request: "GET /request-cres.html?id=23 HTTP/1.1", host: "***.eu"

2018/12/02 00:40:01 [warn] 7738#7738: *208933 delaying request, excess: 2.850, by zone "***.eu", client: 185.***.***.***, server: ***.eu, request: "GET /request-cres.html?id=3 HTTP/1.1", host: "***.eu"

2018/12/02 00:40:01 [warn] 7738#7738: *208939 delaying request, excess: 0.940, by zone "***.eu", client: 185.**.**.**, server: ***.eu, request: "GET /request-touap.html HTTP/1.1", host: "***.eu"

2018/12/02 00:41:01 [warn] 7738#7738: *208950 delaying request, excess: 0.910, by zone "****.eu", client: 185.**.**.*, server: ****.eu, request: "GET /merchant-qiwinew_cron.html HTTP/1.1", host: "****.eu"
```

Причём только один важный для меня крон не работает, остальные, к примеру, парсер - работает исправно.

О чём говорит эта ошибка? В сервере дело или с кодом какие-то проблемы? Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда "копать" для поиска решений.

Comment: 1. к программе *cron* вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения. 2. к ошибкам вопрос не имеет никакого отношения. 3. вопрос имеет отношение к предупреждению (warning по-английски).

Comment: Спасибо за перевод. Error - ошибка ; warning - предупреждение. В связи с чем ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ появляется?

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html